# PHP rand() advise

Tags: php

I am using the following code

```
$wID=rand(2, 4);
```

to generate numbers from 2 to 4, how can i generate numbers starting from 2 but no maximum?

Comment: There is always a maximum... the max int size.  This is even smaller on some platforms.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getrandmax.php

Comment: Do you mean the largest possible number given your current numeric precision? Use that number as your second parameter to `rand()`.

Comment: Just take an extraordinary high max value, infinity is not yet provided in computers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [mt_rand](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) (it's better).

> how can i generate numbers starting from 2 but no maximum?

No computer can produce an infinite set of numbers.

If you call `mt_rand` without arguments, it will return a number between `0` and the value of [mt_getrandmax()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-getrandmax.php). So, if you want, you can do:

```
$wID = mt_rand() + 2;
```

or:

```
$wID = mt_rand(2, mt_getrandmax());
```

or just enter a very high max of your choosing.

Comment: mt_rand? whats the difference

Comment: According to the docs `mt_rand` will "generate a better random value."